# JQuery AJAX - How to refresh/reload page using a method GET call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For some reason I can't make this code work, I am trying to reload/refresh the page using GET. All the sample codes that I have found uses POST but I can't go to that because our forms require GET.

This is my code:

```
        $.ajax({type: "GET", 
            url: "CorrectResults", 
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() { 
                console.log("Submitting Data");               
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) { 
                  document.location.reload();
                  //location.reload(true);
                  //$("#acceptDiv").html(html);             
           }          
        });
```

It should be a simple way to get this done, why this is so easy with POST and not with GET?

Comment: Do you have the right URL? What error exactly do you get?

Comment: why are you doing ajax if after it you refresh the page lol?

Comment: You aren't reloading the page using GET (well, you are, but not in the way you think). You are making an Ajax request and when it is successful, you are reloading the page. The type of Ajax request you make is utterly irrelevant as far as this is concerned. (The fact you are reloading the page after you make the Ajax request renders using Ajax pointless though, the whole point of Ajax is that it lets you make requests **without** reloading the page)

Comment: did you try window.location.reload()?

Comment: You can try window.location.href=window.location.href. It doesn't include the POST data.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input guys. Dear Quentin, we are using AJAX because there some portions that need to be rendered when page launches first time, but, when we summit new changes, we need to reload the whole page. Btw, rba & rkc88 I will try your approach.

Comment: rkc88 and rba, I have tested your approach but it does not work. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", 
            url: "CorrectResults", 
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() { 
                console.log("Submitting Data");               
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) { 
                  window.location.href= "../yourUrl";          
           }          
        });
```

Hope it helps;)

Comment: @LiveStreamX if it helps , pls check up as fixed ;) thanx

Comment: I practised it .. ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you have not any other error in your script( please go to console in your browser press F12),
then you can try with `location.reload();`
in your success method, like that:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", 
            url: "CorrectResults", 
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() { 
                console.log("Submitting Data");               
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) { 
                  location.reload();      
           }          
        });
```

Comment: Please mark my answer :) if it helpful to you 
thanks